# Update pattern: updating changes every node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to get my head around how to update only those `d3` nodes where the data has changed but I still don't have it right. In the little test example below, I am still changing everything it seems.

Am I doing this completely wrong or just a little wrong?

In the example, a click on a shape toggles the shape to be a circle or square and updates a "clickCnt" property. Then it redraws the data. It's sort of working but seems to be redrawing everything. Also clicking on the "red" shape is not working for some reason yet it is the exact same code.

```js
var dataArray = [];
dataArray.push({ "label": 'red', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 30, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'orange', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 110, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'yellow', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 210, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'green', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 310, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'blue', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 30, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'indigo', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 110, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'violet', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 210, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'white', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 310, y: 200 });

var width = 400;
var height = 400;

d3.select("div#svg-container").select("svg").remove();
var svg = d3.select("#svg-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var content = svg.append("g")

function create(data) {
    var groups = content.selectAll("g")
        .data(data, function (d) {
            return d;
        });

    groups.exit().remove();

    groups.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'
        })
        .each(function (d) {
            var e = d3.select(this);
            e.append("text")
                .classed("small-text", true)
                .classed("label", true)
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                })
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                });

            e.append("text")
                .classed("small-text", true)
                .classed("clickCnt", true)
                .attr("y", 20)
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.clickCnt;
                })
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                })

            if (d.shape == "circle") {
                e.append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "circle")
                    .attr("r", 15)
                    .attr("cx", 10)
                    .attr("cy", -40)
                    .on("click", iconClicked)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer");

            } else if (d.shape == "square") {
                e.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "square")
                    .attr("width", 30)
                    .attr("height", 30)
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .attr("y", -55)
                    .on("click", iconClicked)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer");
            }
        });
}


create(dataArray);

function iconClicked(evt) {
    if (evt.shape == "circle") {
        evt.shape = "square"
    } else if (evt.shape == "square") {
        evt.shape = "circle"
    }
    evt.clickCnt++;

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "item clicked: " + evt.label + " " + evt.clickCnt;
    
    create(dataArray);
}
```

```css
    .circle {
      stroke: red;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      
    }
    .square {
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    #timeline-background {
      background: slategray;
    }

    .label {
      fill: blue;
    }
    .small-text {
      font-size: 16px;
      
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <label id="output">out</label>
  <div id="timeline-background" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="svg-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Spring: the answer below of such quality and specificity that it was/is almost certainly an answer that could be accepted. Do you think, given that the question is unlikely to attract new answers, that you could accept this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is the [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#joining-data) when you bind the data.

If you look at the documentation, you'll see that:

> A key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index, by computing a **string** identifier for each datum and element. (emphasis mine)

However, in your case, instead of using a string, you're returning a whole object:

```
var groups = content.selectAll("g")
    .data(data, function (d) {
        return d;
        //     ^--- this is an object
    });
```

And, of course, this won't work.

Because of that, we have the behaviour you described: your `exit` selection contains all groups and they are all removed. Then, the enter selection contains all elements, and they are all painted again.

Let's see it, click the elements and have a look at the console:

```js
var dataArray = [];
dataArray.push({ "label": 'red', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 30, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'orange', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 110, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'yellow', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 210, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'green', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 310, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'blue', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 30, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'indigo', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 110, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'violet', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 210, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'white', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 310, y: 200 });

var width = 400;
var height = 400;

d3.select("div#svg-container").select("svg").remove();
var svg = d3.select("#svg-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var content = svg.append("g")

function create(data) {
    var groups = content.selectAll("g")
        .data(data, function (d) {
            return d;
        });
        
    console.log("The exit selection size is: " + groups.exit().size())

    groups.exit().remove();

    groups.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'
        })
        .each(function (d) {
            var e = d3.select(this);
            e.append("text")
                .classed("small-text", true)
                .classed("label", true)
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                })
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                });

            e.append("text")
                .classed("small-text", true)
                .classed("clickCnt", true)
                .attr("y", 20)
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.clickCnt;
                })
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                })

            if (d.shape == "circle") {
                e.append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "circle")
                    .attr("r", 15)
                    .attr("cx", 10)
                    .attr("cy", -40)
                    .on("click", iconClicked)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer");

            } else if (d.shape == "square") {
                e.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "square")
                    .attr("width", 30)
                    .attr("height", 30)
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .attr("y", -55)
                    .on("click", iconClicked)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer");
            }
        });
}


create(dataArray);

function iconClicked(evt) {
    if (evt.shape == "circle") {
        evt.shape = "square"
    } else if (evt.shape == "square") {
        evt.shape = "circle"
    }
    evt.clickCnt++;

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "item clicked: " + evt.label + " " + evt.clickCnt;
    
    create(dataArray);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}
.circle {
      stroke: red;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      
    }
    .square {
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    #timeline-background {
      background: slategray;
    }

    .label {
      fill: blue;
    }
    .small-text {
      font-size: 16px;
      
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <label id="output">out</label>
  <div id="timeline-background" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="svg-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**(partial) Solution**: Use a unique string as the returned value, such as the `label` property:

```
var groups = content.selectAll("g")
    .data(data, function (d) {
        return d.label;
    });
```

Have a look:

```js
var dataArray = [];
dataArray.push({ "label": 'red', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 30, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'orange', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 110, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'yellow', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 210, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'green', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 310, y: 100 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'blue', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 30, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'indigo', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 110, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'violet', "shape": "circle", "clickCnt": 0, x: 210, y: 200 });
dataArray.push({ "label": 'white', "shape": "square", "clickCnt": 0, x: 310, y: 200 });

var width = 400;
var height = 400;

d3.select("div#svg-container").select("svg").remove();
var svg = d3.select("#svg-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var content = svg.append("g")

function create(data) {
    var groups = content.selectAll("g")
        .data(data, function (d) {
            return d.label;
        });
        
    console.log("The exit selection size is: " + groups.exit().size())

    groups.exit().remove();

    groups.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'
        })
        .each(function (d) {
            var e = d3.select(this);
            e.append("text")
                .classed("small-text", true)
                .classed("label", true)
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                })
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                });

            e.append("text")
                .classed("small-text", true)
                .classed("clickCnt", true)
                .attr("y", 20)
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.clickCnt;
                })
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d.label;
                })

            if (d.shape == "circle") {
                e.append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "circle")
                    .attr("r", 15)
                    .attr("cx", 10)
                    .attr("cy", -40)
                    .on("click", iconClicked)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer");

            } else if (d.shape == "square") {
                e.append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "square")
                    .attr("width", 30)
                    .attr("height", 30)
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .attr("y", -55)
                    .on("click", iconClicked)
                    .style("cursor", "pointer");
            }
        });
}


create(dataArray);

function iconClicked(evt) {
    if (evt.shape == "circle") {
        evt.shape = "square"
    } else if (evt.shape == "square") {
        evt.shape = "circle"
    }
    evt.clickCnt++;

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "item clicked: " + evt.label + " " + evt.clickCnt;
    
    create(dataArray);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}
.circle {
      stroke: red;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      
    }
    .square {
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    #timeline-background {
      background: slategray;
    }

    .label {
      fill: blue;
    }
    .small-text {
      font-size: 16px;
      
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <label id="output">out</label>
  <div id="timeline-background" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="svg-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now, as you can see, the `exit` selection's size is always zero.

However, I wrote *partial* for a reason: you're not changing the elements anymore! The explanation is that you don't have a proper update selection. Since the exit selection has no element anymore, the size of the enter selection is also zero. Nothing is updated here.

Creating such update selection is beyond the scope of this answer and I'll leave that work to you.